# how to implemment auto detect otp using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I have implemented OTP verification using firebase,now I want add auto-detect OTP verification functionality in tha. But before autodetect app should ask about the permission for auto detect. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You Go

in gradle

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'
```

```
class SMSReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private var otpListener: OTPReceiveListener? = null

    fun setOTPListener(otpListener: OTPReceiveListener?) {
        this.otpListener = otpListener
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION) {
            val extras = intent.extras
            val status = extras!![SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS] as Status?
            when (status!!.statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                    val sms = extras[SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE] as String?
                    sms?.let {
                        val p = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                        val m = p.matcher(it)
                        if (m.find()) {
                            val otp = m.group()
                            if (otpListener != null) {
                                otpListener!!.onOTPReceived(otp)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface OTPReceiveListener {
        fun onOTPReceived(otp: String?)
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<receiver
   android:name=".SMSReceiver"
   android:exported="true"
   android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: this code should be in verify activitiy or have to create another class for that?

Comment: you can do whatever you like you can put it in activity or create new class for this. but here I have provided new class then make it easy and create new class ;-)